# 981 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook-login

This '981 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64' errors comes when i build ios project in xcode.

Actually i configured facebook login in iOS project using react-native-fbsdk. I followed the facebook official documentation, after that bunch of errors comes first 'frameworks not found' errors was comming. I added these 4 frameworks in target -> build phases -> Link binaries with libraries according to some stackoverflow solution.

See[image: Link Binaries With libraries]

The frameworks errors gone, then '981 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64' errors comes on build.

I also added some configution in ios/[project_name]/AppDelegate.mm file as facebook documentation said. I imported `#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>`and pasted below function

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
          openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
       annotation:(id)annotation {
  // Handle Facebook URL
  // BOOL handledFacebookURL =
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                             openURL:url
                                   sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                          annotation:annotation];

  // Handle React Native URL
  // BOOL handledReactNativeURL =
  [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                     openURL:url
           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                  annotation:annotation];

  // Return a combined result
  return YES;
}
```

I'm adding and removing -ObjC flag in target, project->build settings-> other linker flags accourding to some solutions i googled it, but didn't work